# Library to compare two .proto files for equal message ids

Tags: protocol-buffers

In my current project, I am persisting protobufs with enums. To ensure backwards compatibility, I need to make sure that these enums stay the same and I want to write unit tests for that.

Example:

legacy_mood.proto:

```
enum Mood {
  HAPPY = 0;
  SAD = 1;
}
```

mood.proto:

```
enum Mood {
  EXCITED = 0;
  HAPPY = 1;
  SAD = 2;
}
```

I am looking for a way to compare these two protos, and in this case let the test fail, because the constant value from HAPPY and SAD changed.

I want to allow new values, so I really just want to check equivalence for elements that exist in the legacy proto, so EXCITED should be ignored in this case.

Before I implement this myself, is there a library for that? I've been googleing for a bit now, but couldn't find anything. Could be in Java, C++ or Python

Comment: You might want to check Python protobuf descriptors. They should at least give you a parsed version of the .proto

Comment: Protoc can compile to a descriptor set, which means you can load the data into any platform that can process descriptor.proto - then compare the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

In any of the language you mentioned, you can convert the Enum value A in message Foo to its string representation, and use the string name to get the Enum value B in message Bar, and make sure the two values are equal.

Python API: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#enum